# help with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

i trying to create a regular expression for this pattron

```
field-122 <--the number could be into 0 to 999
```

I develop this regular expression

```
Regex.Replace(htmlString, "field-*([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])", "|", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

But fails when the numbers it's with more that 2 digits. What's wrong in the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one on for size

```
/field-[1-9]?[0-9]{1,2}/
```

If C# regexes don't support the curly brace syntax, this should also work.

```
/field-[1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]/
```

If you want arbitrarily long numbers, you can use

```
/field-[1-9]?[0-9]+/
```

For reference, `?` means **zero or one**, `+` means **one or more**, and `{n,m}` means **at least n and at most m**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you're not searching for the word test, and you're searching for 0 or more `-`'s. The number capturing portion is overly complicated. Try:

```
"fieldText-(\\d{1,3})"
```

Comment: If you want to avoid fieldText-01, then you'll want to add a negative lookahead. `"fieldTest-(?!0\d)(\\d{1,3})"`

Comment: That is correct as long as the input is valid but it would allow 001 and 01. Numbers beginning with zero basically. Depends if this is a valid alternative?

Comment: I doubt that's a problem, but you never know what people are using things for.

Comment: yeah, wasn't being petty with you, just wanted to point it out to the OP before they used it without realising. Regex are very specific and you dont always know what you want until you see what you dont want :) from their original example it seems like they want the two or three digit numbers to start with a 1 which excluded the 001 etc

Comment: Just use `"fieldTest-([1-9]\d{2,3})"`.

Comment: @Dark Slipstream, That means that all numbers have at least three digits, and up to four. I think you were looking for `"fieldTest-([1-9]\d{0,2})"`

Comment: @Dark Slipstream: this doesn't work sorry, if it was correct (Text instead of Test) it would only match 100-9999 not 0-99 (including correction from PaulPRO comment)

Comment: @PaulPRO: I think you have got the most succinct one yet! Its passing all my tests in expresso. Just need to change fieldTest to fieldText :)

Comment: Thanks :) Only thing it would reject that I think he wanted accepted is fieldText-0. so It could be change to account for that: `"fieldText-(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})"`

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback throughout this thread the best version we have collectively come up with is:

```
field-(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})
```

This is basically @PaulPRO's contribution in a comment to another thread modified by myself to reflect the OPs updated requirements (field instead of fieldText).

for these values:

```
field-122
field-1
field-55
field-999
field-0
```

but not these values:

```
field-001
field-01
field-0
field--
field---
field--anything you want here
```

partial match:

```
anything you want herefield-123
```

Comment: Note: remove ^ and $ off the start and end if you are trying to pull this out of a body of text.

Comment: This will not match `field-100`

Comment: @haydenmuhl - I just checked that in Expresso and it validates `field-100` :)